# Post a form with a json object Spring restTemplate

Tags: java, json, spring, curl, resttemplate

I'm trying to write a test that will post a form so I can verify the response. Using swagger I can see the curl request would be:

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d 'listing_id=123&branch_id=123&session_id=1234&name=test%20test&email=test%2Bblacklist%40test.co.uk&phone=01111%20111111&postcode=aa1%2011a&message=Hello%20Test&sender_ip=127.0.0.1' 'http://DOMAIN/FORM/'
```

How can I do this using the spring RestTemplate exchange?

I'm currently trying:

```
  // create request body
        String input = "{\"listing_id\":\"123\",\"branch_id\":\"1234\",\"session_id\":\"bd2aa65c6604ee0eb4b5bb39433f1257\",\"name\":\"Test test\",\"email\":\"me@you.com\",\"phone\":\"01111111111\",\"postcode\":\"aa111a\",\"message\":\"Test\",\"sender_ip\":\"127.0.0.1\"}";

        // set headers
        headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(input, headers);

response = restTestUtils.sendRequest(HttpMethod.POST, urlBuilder.getAgentFormURL(Protocol.HTTP), entity );
```

The response I am getting back is a 500 though:

> 2017-02-06 20:30:10 INFO  RestTestUtils:185 - HTTP METHOD: POST
>   2017-02-06 20:30:10 INFO  RestTestUtils:186 - URL:
>   http://DOMAIN/FORM/ 2017-02-06 20:30:10
>   INFO  RestTestUtils:187 - HEADERS: {Content-Type=[application/json]}
>   2017-02-06 20:30:10 INFO  RestTestUtils:188 - BODY:
>   {"listing_id":"123","branch_id":"1234","session_id":"bd2aa65c6604ee0eb4b5bb39433f1257","name":"Test
>   test","email":"me@you.com","phone":"01111111111","postcode":"a1111a","message":"Test","sender_ip":"127.0.0.1"}
>
> 2017-02-06 20:30:10 INFO  APIStepDefinations:192 -
>   ContactForm{"error":{"status":"500","message":"Can't use an undefined
>   value as a HASH reference at
>   /usr/local/share/perl5/Internal/Controller/Lead/Form/Listing.pm line
>   86.\n","code":"internal_server_error"}} 2017-02-06 20:30:10 INFO  APIStepDefinations:140 - actualStatusCode:500
>   expectedHTTPStatusCode:200

That error response is what the API is coming back with so I'm clearly making a bad request. What is the correct way using Spring? I think it might be to do with the name not being encoded like on the curl version, but if I encode it the response says it failed validation because it thinks I entered one name not two.

Comment: Look at the *Content-Type*. With teh curl is *application/x-www-form-urlencoded*, on RestTemplate is *application/json*.

Comment: Thanks I've changed it I now see HEADERS: {Content-Type=[application/x-www-form-urlencoded]} but I still get the same error response coming back

Comment: the point is you should send an URL encoded string as payload, not a json. And you have the line error of your server script, so you can debug and check for further errors.